# Visual Studio Community Version 17.7.4 Http Test 401 Errors

Tags: visual-studio, httptestingcontroller

Since upgrading my Visual Studio Community edition to Version 17.7.4, I noticed that the method of sending requests in an http test document has changed in the UI from a green play button to a “Send Request” link. More importantly, since this update all of my test requests now return “401 Unauthorized” responses. I do get successful responses from the Swagger window, and pasting the GET URL into a Chrome browser also returns a successful response. Postman also returns 401 errors.
Is there a known breaking change in this version?

Comment: I have since found that the Postman error is unrelated.  I fixed it, so now Postman and Swagger process requests without error, but the http test window still returns 401 errors.